# How to increase font-size

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, navigation, theme, top-navigation

I am new to SharePoint online and I was wondering if you can help me with my question:

1. How I can change the top navigation style, for-instance font-size, color, font-family?

Answer (score 0):

On communication sites, you can change the theme and header, layout of your navigation and add a footer to your site.

[image][image]

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-look-of-your-sharepoint-site-06bbadc3-6b04-4a60-9d14-894f6a170818

Answer (score 0):

You can change the navigation styling in SharePoint online modern experience from **Settings** >> **Change the look**.

[image]

**Reference**: [Change the look of your SharePoint site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-look-of-your-sharepoint-site-06bbadc3-6b04-4a60-9d14-894f6a170818)

---

If you are not happy with the standard themes, you can also define custom themes, custom styles and colors to sites.

**References**:

1. [SharePoint site theming](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-theming/sharepoint-site-theming-overview)
2. [Fluent UI Theme Designer](https://fluentuipr.z22.web.core.windows.net/heads/master/theming-designer/index.html)
3. [SharePoint site theming: JSON schema](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-theming/sharepoint-site-theming-json-schema)

Comment: Hi @Harris, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you in any way & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.